# Python: join strings from a list under certain patterns

Tags: python

there's a list of strings that I'm trying to break it down in a specific pattern. 
The list looks like this:

```
['a', 'b', '\n', 'text1', 'text2', '\n', 'a', 'b', '\n', 'text1', 'text2', 'text3', '\n']
```

so we know for certain that 'a' and 'b' repeat, but 'text1','text2'...'textn' come in different numbers of times. Sometimes more than the other; and my goal is to join all the 'text1'...'textn' together.

The end result would look like this:

```
[['a', 'b', 'text1 text 2'], ['a', 'b', 'text1 text 2 text3']]
```

This is what I have so far:

```
list = []
for t in lines:
    d = ''
    for t in lines:
        if "\a\" not in t and "\b\" not in t and t != '\n':
            d = d + t
```

Comment: Have you tried to use `regex`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
lines = ['a', 'b', '\n', 'text1', 'text2', '\n', 'a', 'b', '\n', 'text1', 'text2', 'text3', '\n']

def group(seq, sep):
    g = []
    for el in seq:
        if el == sep:
            yield g
            g = []
        g.append(el)
    yield g

result = list(group(lines, '\n'))

for item in range(0,len(result)):
    if item%2==1 :
        x=''
        for i in result[item] :
            if i=='\n':
                i=''
            x+=i+' '
        result[item]=[x]

for item in result :
    if item[0]=='\n':
        item.remove(item[0])

result = [x for x in result if x != []]
final = []

for i in range(0,len(result)):
    if i%2==1 :
        new_list = result[0]+result[i]
        final.append(new_list)
print(final)
```

output :

```
[['a', 'b', ' text1 text2 '], ['a', 'b', ' text1 text2 text3 ']]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this though it may not be an efficient way

```
x=['a', 'b', '\n', 'text1', 'text2', '\n', 'a', 'b', '\n', 'text1', 'text2', 'text3', '\n']
old_element=''
new_list=[]
sub_list=[]
for i,element in enumerate(x):
    if element == 'a' or element == 'b':
        sub_list.append(element)
    elif element == '\n' and old_element == 'b':
        sub_list.append('')
    elif element == '\n':
        new_list.append(sub_list)
        sub_list=[]
    else:
        sub_list[-1]=sub_list[-1]+ element + " "
    old_element = element
print(new_list)
```

output

```
[['a', 'b', 'text1 text2 '], ['a', 'b', 'text1 text2 text3 ']]
```